# Is there any way to scan handwritten UML diagrams into a UML tool?

Tags: uml, ocr

I find using UML tools quite cumbersome and no one could ever accuse me of having been particularly productive while using them. Is there any tool out which can do Optical Diagram Recognition and produce an editable document from my back-of-a-fag-packet sketch?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of (and I look for them for a while some time ago). The problem is not so much recognizing the shapes in your diagram but recognizing your handwriting. Unless your handwriting was very clear (e.g. with a clear separation of characters) you don't have many chances of succeed.